# Would it be possible to loan a cryptocurrency and get interest?

Tags: blockchain

Would it be  possible (future) to loan a blockchain (crypto) and get interest? (Like bank would lend money to user who needs it and gives interest to who invest?)

Comment: https://loanscan.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are various lending platforms. Probably the most popular one is Aave. You can read more about its functionality here: https://docs.aave.com/faq/